# ADOConnection ADOQuery CommandTimeout , Override Order ( if at all )

Tags: delphi, ado

Got here Delphi 10.4.2 . One ADOConnection and one ADOQuery .

ADOConnection uses OleDB (UDL) to connect to MSSQL. And I have left the CommandTimeout 30 .
Now I place the ADOQuery on this form set it's Connection property to ADOConnection . All other Values are at default , CommandTimeout is 30 .

Now let's imagine we have a very large table which timeouts. With the default 30 Seconds .

My problem is :

if I set ADOQuery CommandTimeout to 600 it works
but If I only set ADOConnection CommandTimeout to 600 it still makes a timeout

What purpose does CommandTimeout on ADOConnection have if it does not simply propagate it's values to it's associated components ( until of course I override them ) ?

Thank you.

**EDIT 1 :**

Is it that the ADOConnection CommandTimeout is used actually for some background tasks which ADOConnection must do to build the connection ?
For example if I in the IDE Activate it , and then have a ADOStoredProcedure and I want to list all the available Stored Procedures on the Server it uses this timeout?

Comment: Without much db experience, I only comment: `TADOConnection` has a property `ConnectionTimeout` to stop if the connection takes too long. In addition it can have commands in its `Commands` property and have a `CommandTimeout` property for those commands. If, instead, you use `TADOCommand` instances for commands, they have their own `CommandTimeout` property. Same with `ADOQuery` queries, they have their own `CommandTimeout` property. Isn't that quite logical?

Comment: Do you program like you write? With spaces in front of the punctuation? Like `Query .CommandTimeout :=30 ;`? I'm really interested on the reasons why people do these extra spaces, because I cannot find any logical one for it.

Comment: @AmigoJack : no offence but you are seeing things which are not there :) . ADOQuery CommandTimeout there is no . inbetween , I just wrote it like that . LIke I would write , BMW F20 for example .

Comment: @AmigoJack : I usually do ADOQuery.CommandTimeout_:=_true; ( _ = space )

Comment: @TomBrunberg : I guess that makes sense, I guess the problem here is also that I do not fully understand how the Component works in the Background.

Comment: According to MS they should not interfere : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/commandtimeout-property-ado?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/commandtimeout-property-ado?view=sql-server-ver15) each ADO object respects its own `CommandTimeout`:

> The CommandTimeout setting on a Connection object has no effect on the
> CommandTimeout setting on a Command object on the same Connection;
> that is, the Command object's CommandTimeout property does not inherit
> the value of the Connection object's CommandTimeout value.

I made a small MRE (Using Delphi 10.3)  to prove this point:

```
program SO69733529;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  ActiveX,
  AdoDb,
  System.SysUtils;

procedure TestADOCommandTimeout;

var
  Conn : TADOConnection;
  Qry  : TADOQuery;
  SQLDelay : Integer;

begin
 Conn := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
 Qry := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
 try
  Conn.LoginPrompt := False;
  Conn.ConnectionString := 'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=TestCustomer;Integrated Security = SSPI;';
  Conn.Connected := True;
  Qry.Connection := Conn;
  Writeln('Connected to DB');
  SQLDelay := 10;
  Conn.CommandTimeout := 5;
  try
   Writeln(Format('Waiting for %d seconds, connection timeout is %d seconds', [SQLDelay, Conn.CommandTimeout]));
   Conn.Execute(Format('WAITFOR DELAY ''00:00:%.2d''', [SQLDelay]));
   Writeln('No Timeout');
  except
   on E: Exception do
    Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Qry.CommandTimeout := 30;
  try
   Writeln(Format('Waiting for %d seconds, query timeout is %d seconds, connection timeout is %d seconds', [SQLDelay, Qry.CommandTimeout, Conn.CommandTimeout]));
   Qry.SQL.Text := Format('WAITFOR DELAY ''00:00:%.2d''', [SQLDelay]);
   Qry.ExecSQL;
   Writeln('No Timeout');
  except
   on E: Exception do
    Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  // now redo the same test but with connection commandtimeout same as qry timeout
  Qry.CommandTimeout := 15;
  Conn.CommandTimeout := Qry.CommandTimeout;
  try
   Writeln(Format('Waiting for %d seconds, query timeout is %d seconds, connection timeout is %d seconds', [SQLDelay, Qry.CommandTimeout, Conn.CommandTimeout]));
   Qry.SQL.Text := Format('WAITFOR DELAY ''00:00:%.2d''', [SQLDelay]);
   Qry.ExecSQL;
   Writeln('No Timeout');
  except
   on E: Exception do
    Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;    
 finally
  Qry.Free;
  Conn.Free;
 end;
end;

begin
  try
   try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    TestADOCommandTimeout;
   finally
     CoUninitialize;
   end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
 Readln;
end.
```

Output:

```
 Connected to DB Waiting for 10 seconds, connection timeout is 5 seconds
 EOleException: Query timeout expired 
 Waiting for 10 seconds, query timeout is 30 seconds, connection timeout is 5 seconds  
 No Timeout 
 Waiting for 10 seconds, query timeout is 15 seconds, connection timeout is 15 seconds 
 No Timeout
```